# layout margin for text view programmatically

Tags: android

If I use xml file I have a option called layout_margin (for example layout_margin ="1dp" for text view ) but I want to set programmatically and I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically

Comment: please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814124/how-to-change-margin-of-textview

Comment: Please see this way at KOTLIN https://stackoverflow.com/a/72072222/12272687

Answer (score 15):

```
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)textview.getLayoutParams();
     params.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0); 
     textview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 6):

Please Google before adding your question to StackOverflow.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do by this:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);   
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);//pass int values for left,top,right,bottom
text.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I precise , its : 
params.setMargins(text.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);//pass int values for left,top,right,bottom
params.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: I am getting api lvl 19 required for this

Answer (score 3):

Note, that not all LayoutParams has method setMargins();

RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc has their own inner class LayoutParams, so availability of setMargins is not always available.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvId);   
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llp.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This: It worked...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

 params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);

firstName.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I don't know if you have really tested it but as of 07.23 it is full of errors and you don't name variables starting with the capital letter. I don't recommend you nswering questions without really testing them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setMargins()` on the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. See the answer of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481517/1482726) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_title));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mRelativelp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv
                    .getLayoutParams();
        mRelativelp.setMargins(DptoPxConvertion(15), 0, DptoPxConvertion (15), 0);
        tv.setLayoutParams(mRelativelp);

    private int DptoPxConvertion(int dpValue)
    {
       return (int)((dpValue * mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) + 0.5);
    }
```

getLayoutParams() of textview should be casted to the corresponding Params based on the **Parent of the textview in xml**.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title">
</RelativeLayout>
```

If parent of the TextView is RelativeLayout means, then RelativeLayout.LayoutParams as above. If parent is LinearLayout means then

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mLinearlp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tv
                    .getLayoutParams();
```

To render the same real size on different devices use DptoPxConvertion() method which I have used above. setMargin(left,top,right,bottom) params will take **values in pixel not in dp**.