# How to set margins for TextView programmatically?

Tags: android, textview

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);      
tv1.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv1.setTextSize(11);
tv1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
tv1.setText("Test1");
ll.addView(tv1);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);      
tv2.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099cc"));
tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv2.setTextSize(11);
tv2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
tv2.setText("Test2");
ll.addView(tv2);
```

As you can see, in this peace of code I set `TextView`'s background color. What I want to do is I want to separate both of these `TextView`'s from each other, so that their background colors would be separated by a line. I don't want them to connect. As I understand, it would be possible to do so, if I could set margins of `TextView`, but as I know, `TextView`'s are not able to do so.

Comment: Where you are going to add these textViews?

Comment: Why you are not adding view in your xml file... like this<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#7C56C3" />

Answer (score 186, accepted):

set to LayoutParams.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: @SanjayKumar nope, API Level 1 can use this call. I made an example based on this answer. check https://github.com/shanwu/shanwu_coding_base/tree/programatically_add_textview_example

Comment: In which unit it will set margin, means in dp,px,sp or something else?

Comment: For some reason I am getting a warning that this requires min api lvl 19 make sense?

Comment: You actually don't need the last `tv1.setLayoutParams(params);`. Java passes references!

Comment: @RahulSharma it sets it in px

Comment: @Cigogne Eveillée in the above case since a new params object is created, it is needed. If params would have been obtained from the textview, then yes, what you are saying would be correct: tv1.getlayoutParams().set..()

Comment: Why do you use ```LinearLayout``` to set ```LayoutParams``` ?
I mean is it because of this example or is must be done every time this way?

Comment: Sets the margins, in pixels.

Answer (score 13):

It depends according to your parent view.

If you using LinearLayout on your textview as a parent view give params like below

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If you using RelativeLayout on your textview as a parent view give params like below

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 8):

For Kotlin use following code snippet

```
(textView.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
        marginStart=8.dpToPixels()
        topMargin=8.dpToPixels()
        marginEnd=8.dpToPixels()
        bottomMargin=8.dpToPixels()
    }
```

Change LayoutParams as per used layout.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin I do like this:

```
    binding.playBtn.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
        setMargins(0,16,0,0) //parameters are in pixel
    }
    binding.playBtn.setPadding(10)
```

Answer (score 6):

All these answers are great, but I was using ConstraintLayout, so here is code for that:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
textview.setLayoutParams(params); // note that textview would be your instanced TextView object
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should be tried

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10,20,30,20);
        txt_gender.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Kotlin Extensions:**

Here is simple extension for setting margins for textview.

```
fun View.setMargins(marginLeft: Int, marginTop: Int, marginRight: Int, marginBottom: Int) {
  val params: LinearLayout.LayoutParams =
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
  params.setMargins(margin.dp, 0, margin.dp, 0)
  this.layoutParams = params
}
```

For `Int` to `dp` conversion, here is another extension

```
val Int.dp: Int
  get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

You can call this extension to give horizontal margin 8dp as follows

```
yourTextView.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

set margins for TextView programmatically

Here The way That you can use it any where in your Application

create a Object class and add this code there

```
    fun setMargin(left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, textView: TextView){
    val params: LinearLayout.LayoutParams =
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
    textView.setLayoutParams(params)
}
```

Then you can call it anywhere and use it for any TextView of course you can change the layout for anything you want.

you can call this function like this.

```
setMargin(0, 70, 0, 0, title)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the margin to any textview with this simple code

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(20, 30, 40, 50);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Kotlin** ex. in `Adapter` add like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val params = holder.tvNext.layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams
        params.bottomMargin=0
```