# Android set margin of textview programmatically

Tags: android

When I try to set a margin with this code:

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStart();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
TextView login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
int text_height = login.getHeight();
int text_whidth= login.getWidth();
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)login.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT, (int)login.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 500, 0, 0);

login.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

The app crashes on start.  How can I set margin without it crashing my app?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.alrikh.altervista.org/logjj.txt

Comment: Please see this way at KOTLIN https://stackoverflow.com/a/72072222/12272687

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace the following line:

```
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)login.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT, (int)login.getLayoutParams().WRAP_CONTENT);
```

with this one:

```
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: So probably one of your variables is 'null'. But I suggest you to use my offer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

here is Method for you, just need to pass parameters

```
public static void setMargin(View view, int left, int right, int top, int bottom) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
    view.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

where First Parameter view is Your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutParams having `setMargins` method and then set params to `setLayoutParams()` method of `TextView`.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(10,10,10,10); // setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```