# Adding Dynamic Text View

Tags: java, android

Trying to create notes application. I am trying to add dynamic text view after button click and it should be added to layout, one after another. In my code, only one text view is getting added successfully but from second time, app got crashed. Please help

XML Code:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_thingsToDo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ThingsToDo_EditText_Width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ThingsToDo_EditText_Height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/Standardize_Margin"
        android:background="@color/ThingsToDo_EditText_Color"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_thingsToDo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_thingsToDo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ThingsToDo_Save_Button_Text"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Standardize_Margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Standardize_Margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Standardize_Margin"
        android:background="@color/ThingsToDo_Save_Button"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Java Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_things_to_do);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_thingsToDo);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_thingsToDo);
    final TextView notesView = new TextView(this);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView_ThingsToDo);
    final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notesView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
            linearLayout.addView(notesView);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps create a new TextView every time you press the button? Try to declare the TextView as a class member and then in your `OnClickListener` do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        notesView = new TextView(this);
        notesView.setText(editText.getText().toString());
        linearLayout.addView(notesView);
    }
});
```

Hopefully this will fix your problem!

Comment: Not a porblem. Happy coding!

Comment: One more help, do you know how to add margin to this dynamically created text view. I am unable to add it. Because there is a option to add padding but no option for margin.

Comment: You should use LayoutParams to set margins. Check out this link for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15636479/7803448

Comment: Today you made my day. God bless you :)

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161667/discussion-between-lucifer-and-matthew-vanlandingham).