# how to change constraint margin in my constraint layout programatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a textview like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_data_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_dark_top"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="data in here" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

as you can see, I set the top and bottom margin to be 8 dp. but I need to change that top and bottom constraint to be 32 dp when it is met certain condition. so I need to change it programmatically. how to do that ?

Comment: Logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636401/how-to-set-margins-for-textview-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:-

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params= (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
    textView.getLayoutParams();
    int margin=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.vertical_padding_small);
    params.topMargin=margin;
    params.bottomMargin=margin;
```