# change xml value android:layout_marginStart of ImageView in Java Android Widget

Tags: android, xml, widget, imageview, margins

I created a xml file with a ImageView Widget and i want to change the position of this ImageView with the xml value android:layout_marginStart programmatically with Java. I want to set the value in Java and update the Widget. How can i change the value ? findVIewById cant be used for Widgets...

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plane"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp" <-- i want to change this value with java code
            android:contentDescription="@string/plane"
            android:src="@drawable/plane"/>
```

Comment: I`m not working on the main App. I created an App Widget( like a weather widget) and i want to change the xml value there.

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636401/how-to-set-margins-for-textview-programmatically

Comment: There's really no way you're gonna get access to `LayoutParams` in an external hierarchy, so this is just not possible directly. If you're going to have only a few possible positions, you could put multiple `<ImageView>`s in the layout, each at a different margin, and set the visibility on them as needed. Otherwise, the only other thing that comes to mind atm is using `RemoteViews#setFloat()` to call the `ImageView`'s `setX()`, `setTranslationX()`, etc. methods, but that might not behave as expected.

Comment: can i create an ImageView in Java and put it in the widget layout ? so the xml code will be generated ?

Comment: Nope. The only control you have over `View` creation is through the layout XML, and that still can only be generated at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

There is the method `remoteView.setViewPadding(left,right,top,bottom)`. Make sure your Widget has everywhere match_parent and wrap_content and then you can easily use Padding to programmatically change position of Image. probably you have to add `android:cropToPadding="true"` as well.

Comment: Nice find. I don't think I ever knew about that one. Also, it looks like they've added methods specifically for modifying `LayoutParams`, but they aren't available until API level 31; e.g., [`setViewLayoutMargin()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setViewLayoutMargin(int,%20int,%20float,%20int)), which is exactly what you asked for here.